# How to build a standard Linux .so library with stable Rust without using std?

Tags: rust

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "proba"
version = "0.1.0"

[lib]
name = "mycoollib"
path = "src/mycoollib.rs"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

src/mycoollib.rs:

```
#![no_std]

fn func(v: i32) -> i32 {
    v + 10
}
```

When I try to run `cargo build`:

```
error: language item required, but not found: `panic_fmt`
error: language item required, but not found: `eh_personality`
```

A nightly build is needed to implement `panic_fmt` and `eh_personality`, but ["Using Rust Without the Standard Library"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/using-rust-without-the-standard-library.html) of the Rust book says that libs can build on stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the documentation is misleading in this case. The problem is in the definition of the word "library".

A Rust library (sometimes known as an *rlib*) can use `#[no_std]` and not require definitions for `panic_fmt` or `eh_personality`. That's because *eventually* it will be linked against into a binary that does use the standard library, which defines these symbols.

A native library (either `dylib`, `cdylib`, or probably `staticlib`) has no guarantee of being linked with these symbols / language items, so they must be defined up front.

As you can see, both of these could be called a "library". I think that the book is being a little loose with the terminology, leading to the confusion.